# Execute function once two promises have been finalized

Tags: javascript, promise

I need the function "finalizeProcess" to be executed once all the promises of the "processPhotos" function are finished.

Can anybody help me? 
Thank!!

```
processPhotos();
finalizeProcess();

processPhotos (){
    this.foto1File.generateBlob((blob) => {
        ref.child('picture_1').put(blob)
          .then((pictureRef) => {
            //sentence
          }) 
     })

    this.foto2File.generateBlob((blob) => {
        ref.child('picture_2').put(blob)
          .then((pictureRef) => {
            //sentence
          }) 
     })
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all`.....

Comment: ^ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
function processPhotos() {
  var promise1 = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.foto1File.generateBlob(blob => {
      ref.child('picture_1').put(blob)
        .then(pictureRef => {
          resolve(pictureRef);
        });
    });
  });

  var promise2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.foto2File.generateBlob(blob => {
      ref.child('picture_2').put(blob)
        .then(pictureRef => {
          resolve(pictureRef);
        });
    });
  });

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(results => {
    // do something with results here
    finalizeProcess();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As to what trincot had said, you can use `Promise.all`

Store your functions into a variable and then resolve the promises together.

```
 processPhoto(){

  const firstPromise = this.fotoFile.generateBlob(blob => {
    //[..]

  }
  const secondPromise = this.foto2File.generateBlob(blob => {
     //[...]
   }

 const [foto1File, foto2File] = Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]);
}
```

Of course in each function, make sure to be returning the promise itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here another alternative, similar to the [answer of davmich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913469/3982562). But instead of calling `finalizeProcess` inside `processPhotos` a promise is returned, which you can use to call `finalizeProcess`.

```
function processPhotos() {
  return Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => {
      this.foto1File.generateBlob(blob => {
        ref.child('picture_1').put(blob).then(resolve);
      });
    }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
      this.foto2File.generateBlob(blob => {
        ref.child('picture_2').put(blob).then(resolve);
      });
    })
  ]);
}
```

```
processPhotos().then(pictureRefs => finalizeProcess());
```

---

Alternatively you can unfold to do some processing first.

```
ref.child('picture_1').put(blob).then(resolve);
```

Becomes:

```
ref.child('picture_1').put(blob).then(pictureRef => {
  // do stuff with pictureRef
  resolve(/* custom value */);
});
```